# C# How can I get each column type and length and then use the lenght to padright to get the spaces at the end of each field

Tags: c#, ado.net, metadata, datareader

I have a console application that extracts data from a SQL table to a flat file. How can I get each column type and length and then use the lenght of each column to padright(length) to get the spaces at the end of each field. Here is what I have right now that does not include this functionality.

Thanks

```
{
                var destination = args[0];
                var command = string.Format("Select * from {0}", Validator.Check(args[1]));
                var connectionstring = string.Format("Data Source={0}; Initial Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security=SSPI;", args[2]);

            var helper = new SqlHelper(command, CommandType.Text, connectionstring);

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(destination))
            using (IDataReader reader = helper.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Object[] values = new Object[reader.FieldCount];
                    int fieldCount = reader.GetValues(values);

                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
                        writer.Write(values[i].ToString().PadRight(513));

                    writer.WriteLine();
                }

                writer.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Why not use values[i].ToString().Length?

Comment: @Patko because different rows could have different lengths and he wants to pad all rows consistently, but not more than he really needs to?

Comment: @Cade Roux, of course. I don't know how I failed to see that. Should probably get some sleep..

Comment: Checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71330103/8644294

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IDataReader offers [a GetSchemaTable() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.getschematable(v=VS.100).aspx) which provides a ColumnSize attribute (this varies by the underlying provider - [the SQL Server version is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable(v=VS.100).aspx)).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `DataReader's GetSchemaTable` method to retrieve column schema information. [This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310107) has complete details on getting the metadata about the retrieved data.

Once you have the column size, you can add trailing characters to the retrieved data by using the `String.PadRight` method.